# Set outlook to send files to folder rather than Deleteded items folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, office365, default-settings

Is there a way to change where files go when they are deleted.

were currently running outlook 2013 under Exchange (office 365)

Ideally the solution could specify a directory  that the "deleted" emails go to

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I ask because I don't think there's a way to accomplish what you're asking here, and there may be a better alternative to the actual problem you have.

Comment: That's a function of the application. I don't see how you could alter it's behavior without recoding and recompiling said application.

Comment: @joeqwerty many applications have configurable functions that don't require changes to code.

Comment: @techie007 What would a possible alternative be?